# Creating a custom action in Odoo 9

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Information: **Odoo v9 (Windows 10)**

I'm quite new to Odoo development and i can't seem to get a grip of it.. sadly.

My problem is that i have no clue how i can create a custom action menu item. I have tried Google quite a few times but i never quite arrived at a solution or example that would give me a hint... at all!

Specific details about my problem:
I would like to add a custom menu entry in the **"Sales Orders"** Overview.

There is a menu in the middle which states **"Print"** and **"Action"**.
*I would like to add a custom entry to* **"Action"**... But i have no idea how to go about it.

I'm sorry if this question was asked already - I was unable to find anything related on the web.

A example would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you all in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an example :

```xml
<act_window
            name="Entries"
            id="act_account_acount_move_line_open"
            res_model="account.move.line"
            src_model="account.account"
            context="{'default_account_id': active_id}"
            />
```

What should you know :

`src_model` : define witch model that this action will be added to it's more or action menu

`res_model`: is the model of the action

in `context` it's passing a default value ot m2o `acount_id` witch is the record shown on the current form.

Comment: Thank you very much Cherif Odoo! :)
This helped me immensly! ;)

One question about your answer:
I have entered "sale.order" for both the res_model and src_model... is this correct?
(By the way: The field is now displayed in the action menu! :) )

Comment: usually this technique is used with wizard to do something with the current record and the wizard have a m2o to the same model of the current record. in you case it should open a empty form of sale.order

Comment: in action to pass default value you need to use `default_field_name: 'value'` in my answer the field account_id will be filled with the current record id. in your case try `defaul_name : 'TEST'` then the name will be test not new just play with the code and see what is changing and what errors and you cill learn this greate framework

Comment: Indeed, it sends me (by clicking on the item) to an empty sale.order form. I'm currently trying to find out how i can use a "wizard"... A little lost here again :(

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Chief Odoo :)

Comment: src_model is where you want the action to be added the res_model is what model the action will display it's view you can put any model there. just check the work of odoo developers you will find plainty examples there this is how i learn it by checking what did they use in ir.action_window scan a lot of code to understand what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <act_window id="give a unique name as id"
                name="give a name"
                src_model=""
                res_model=""
                view_type="form" 
                view_mode="form"
                key2="client_action_multi"
                target="new"
                groups=""/>
```

src_model = which particular model you want action
res_model = model to views is to be presented in action

groups is optional,view mode is also optional